# Adding a value to a objects array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, parameter-passing

I have made a node object that populates in an array of 63 x 63. After the first value, it should just access an array attached to the object and put in a value in that array.

The array of objects is defined as:

```
node ** arr[63][63];
```

and my function is this:

```
void addValue(int x, int y, float value)
{
    node a = ** arr[x][y];
    a.valueList[a.size] = value;
    a.size = a.size + 1;

}
```

The idea is that if there is already a node in the array(when the function is called it can be assumed that there already is one), to add the value to "valueList" on the node that already exists at that spot.

here is how it is called in main:

```
                        if(!isValid(arr[xCount][yCount]))
                        {
                            node a(0, false, xCount, yCount);
                            addToArray(&a);
                            myFile.read((char *) &dataIn, 4);
                            yCount++;
                        }
                        else
                            {
                                myFile.read((char *) &dataIn, 4);
                                addValue(xCount, yCount, dataIn);
                                yCount++;
                            }
```

addValue function is crashing the program, and is not properly adding the value to the array attached to the object. I am guessing it might have something to do with how I am accessing the array "arr[][]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole `**` part of the definition of `arr`, as well as in the assignment to `a` -- you don't mention these at all in the text of your question. This leads me to suspect that you didn't actually mean to put them there. It sounds like you want a 2D array of `node`s, rather than a 2D array of pointers to pointers to `node`s. Indeed if you missed that and didn't allocate the nodes and pointers to nodes for the pointers to pointers to nodes to point to, then you'll get a segmentation fault.

BTW, also watch out for `a` being a copy of the array element, changes to which won't get propagated to `arr`.

Comment: When I try to do node arr[63][63]; instead of node ** arr[63][63]; , it gives me a error for no matching constructor

Comment: great, then you've gotten past this error. sounds like next you'll work on initializing an array of objects with no default constructor. good luck!